# Linux : Looking for a distribution or configuration to turn debian/Ubuntu to access only Firefox without accessing data on disk or OS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, security, debian

We have to give a laptop to some people and what we are looking for is that the OS should be secure like bootloader disabled, home-folder encrypted, TTY's disabled and when the OS is active, no access to file-manager, or any other app installation, etc. Keyboard and mouse should also be disabled, so only touch-screen can be used.

The only thing allowed should be firefox, which will be in full-screen and accessible by touch-screen.

I am proficient in Debian based distros and wouldn't mind configuring the OS myself, but if there is something out available or some guide for same, kindly let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Is it not more simple to take out the HDD and give them only a system with a usb pen drive? :-) For what you are searching for I think that you have to manually set the system and take your risks:  if someone physically put  the hands on the computer, he/she can turn off it, open  it, extract the HDD and so on... So balance your efforts for your real needs.

Comment: @Hastur : That is not a problem of them opening laptop, laptop has it's own security, which I am not dealing with. I am more concerned on the software side.

Comment: Software and System sides. Did you consider the fact that if in the firefox bar you write `file:///` you can read the root of your filesystem and from there you can navigate?  Of course you can try each path you want (e.g. `file:///tmp`)... Moreover if you write  `about:config` you have access to the internal setting (...) of firefox. I think this is not the simpler way to approach this problem, but let's we wait someone that will think different. :-)

Comment: @Hastur : Firefox will be full-screen, no keyboard will be available, only touch screen, on-screen keyboard disabling also I found out. Point is, I can only find hacks to disable, but I thought there might be something reliable.